# Can I select multiple files and run external tool in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I'v read this topic : [Running External Tools in PhpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm)

This works fine for running a external tool against a ***single file***.

This is my setting:
`cmd "$FilePath$”`

However, I want to pass ***multiple files*** to the `cmd`, something like below

`cmd file-a.txt file-b.txt file-c.txt`

Can I achieve this in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 5):

Such functionality is not yet implemented.

You may watch (star/vote/comment) after these tickets (or any related tickets) to get notified on progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129069
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97869
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90239

Comment: Not yet implemented... Thank you!